# How to send url(id) through hiddenInput in ActiveForm (Yii2)

Tags: yii2

I am trying to send my URL ID value through ActivForm hidden input, but I didn't get the value.

```
<?= $form->field($modelsRoo, "[{$index}]booking_id")->hiddenInput(
                             ['value'=> '$b_id'])->label(false); ?>
```

I am getting the value from Current Url like this.

and trying to pass it to Activeform HiddenField and on submitting this form I would like to save it in my Table.

One thing more I am using dynamicformwidget.

I am getting the value from Current Url like this:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
 <?=$form->field($modelsRoo, "[{$index}]unit")->textInput(['maxlength' =>true])?></div>

 <div class="col-sm-6">                             
 <?= $form->field($modelsRoo, "[{$index}]booking_id")->hiddenInput(
      ['value'=> '$b_id'])->label(false); ?>
   </div>
```

When I submit the form I get `booking_id` value as Empty.
Any solution.

Comment: Have you got any rule for `booking_id` in your model `rules()` method added?

Comment: And why your value is wrapped in single quotes?

Comment: No sir, I haven't added any rule for booking_id! Actually, I am new to Yii2.

Comment: Kindly tell me how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Read [this section of a Guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-forms) - it explains all you need to know.

Comment: $modelRS = [new RoomServices];                                                                            if ($modelRS->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))                                                  
 How to solve?   Thanks                                                                                                                                    Error: Call to a member function load() on array

Comment: Exactly what error says, you can not call method on array and $modelRS is array here.

Comment: How I can solve this...any alternative? Thanks